# Alternating column layouts in LaTeX (beamer)

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment

I have been using LaTeX beamer for my presentations for some time. My standard slide layout consists of bullet-points on one side, with a 'hook' image on the other. To keep visual interest, I alternate the columns between slides.

A minimal code snippet looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{My Title}
\author{Me}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}    
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}[c]{7cm}
\begin{itemize}
   \item Point One
   \item Point Two
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}[c]{3cm}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{stock/default.png}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}[c]{3cm}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{stock/default.png}
\end{column}
\begin{column}[c]{7cm}
\begin{itemize}
   \item Point Three
   \item Point Four
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Obviously, for longer presentations this alternation can be annoying to code. Also, inserting or removing a slide from the presentation means that the rest of the slides have to be manually realigned. (At the moment I mainly use a vim macro to do it.)

Is there any way to have a variable or parameter that would automatically toggle to correctly swap the columns from slide to slide? I've toyed with the idea of defining a new frame type that takes an 'alignment' argument as well as the relevant text and images, but how to do that, and whether a persistent 'variable' can be kept and set in a LaTeX document, is a significant leap beyond my existing LaTeX knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect the contents of the image column using an environment like `imagecolumn` and the text column using `textcolumn`, and then print the columns via `\printcolumns` as specified below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{environ}
\title{My Title}
\author{Me}

\newlength{\imagecolwidth}\setlength{\imagecolwidth}{3cm}
\newlength{\textcolwidth}\setlength{\textcolwidth}{7cm}

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{imagecolumn}{\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\imagecolcontent\expandafter{\BODY}}
\NewEnviron{textcolumn}{\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\textcolcontent\expandafter{\BODY}}
\newcommand{\printcolumns}{%
  \begin{columns}
    \ifodd\value{page}
      \begin{column}[c]{3cm}
        \imagecolcontent
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}[c]{7cm}
        \textcolcontent
      \end{column}
    \else
      \begin{column}[c]{7cm}
        \textcolcontent
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}[c]{3cm}
        \imagecolcontent
      \end{column}
    \fi
  \end{columns}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}
  \begin{imagecolumn}
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}
  \end{imagecolumn}
  \begin{textcolumn}
    \begin{itemize}
       \item Point One
       \item Point Two
    \end{itemize}
  \end{textcolumn}

  \printcolumns
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{imagecolumn}
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-b}
  \end{imagecolumn}
  \begin{textcolumn}
    \begin{itemize}
       \item Point Three
       \item Point Four
    \end{itemize}
  \end{textcolumn}

  \printcolumns
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to do pretty much exactly what I was looking for, although while I'm at it I'd probably be tempted to wrap up the frame definitions into a macro. Just one question -- what are the '\makeatletter' and '\makeatother' commands? (EDIT: http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=3732 seems to answer the question very well.)

Comment: @user3775311: See [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](http://goo.gl/HYwLd)

Comment: @user3775311: True. I've wrapped it into an environment, but you can do the same via a macro.

Answer (score 1):

You can define each type of frame as a macro in the preamble, where each element that may change is an argument. Assuming that for a consistent format you want always columns of the same width, you need only two arguments: `#1` the item list and `#2` the image. Then, in the body of the document you only need write `\yourmacro{\item ... \item ...}{image}`. An example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{beamer}
\title{Your Title}
\author{You}
\newcommand\LI[2]{
\begin{frame}    
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}[c]{7cm}
\begin{itemize}#1\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}[c]{3cm}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#2}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
}
\newcommand\IL[2]{
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}[c]{3cm}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#2}
\end{column}
\begin{column}[c]{7cm}
\begin{itemize} #1 \end{itemize}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\LI{\item Point One \item Point Two}{example-image-a} 
\IL{\item Point Three \item Point Four}{example-image-b} 

\end{document}
```

If you need this work done with only one macro, one solution if make a conditional loop, for example with `\iftoggle`. A simple example:  the next MWE show a macro that macro `\OddEven{1}{2}` print `12`the first time, but the same command print `21` the second time, the third time `12` again, etc.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{FrameChange}
\toggletrue{FrameChange}
\newcommand\OddEven[2]{
%\iftoggle{FrameChange}%
{#1#2\togglefalse{FrameChange}} % if true
{#2#1\toggletrue{FrameChange}}} % if false

\begin{document}
\OddEven{1}{2} 
\OddEven{1}{2} 
\OddEven{1}{2} 
\OddEven{1}{2} 
\OddEven{1}{2} 
\end{document}
```

Thus, you only need change `#1#2` and `#2#1` by the whole content of the `\LI` and  `\IL` macros from the above example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{FrameChange}
\toggletrue{FrameChange}

\newcommand\OddEven[2]{\iftoggle{FrameChange}{
\begin{frame}    
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}[c]{7cm}
\begin{itemize}#1\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}[c]{3cm}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#2}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\togglefalse{FrameChange}}{

\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}[c]{3cm}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#2}
\end{column}
\begin{column}[c]{7cm}
\begin{itemize} #1 \end{itemize}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\toggletrue{FrameChange}}}

\begin{document}

\OddEven{\item Point One \item Point Two}{example-image-a} 
\OddEven{\item Point Three \item Point Four}{example-image-b} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is almost the sort of thing that I had in mind, but still seems to require manually choosing '\LI' or '\IL'. I think that a wrapper around this that automatically works out which to choose would work well. Some combination of this and Werner's answer will probably sort me out.

Comment: @user3775311, You can convert the two macros in one conditional macro. See the edited answer.